# C# windows form 2 gridviews with synced scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am developing an application in which two datagridviews are being populated from different data sources.  I would like to have a single vertical scroll-bar that will make both gridviews work at the same time (scroll up and down together)

can anyone tell me how or direct me to a good tutorial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have dgv1 and dgv2, you can create something like

```
dgv1.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(dgv1_Scroll);
```

Then, in dgv1_Scroll method, you can use FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property:

```
dgv2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
```

Of course, if dgv's have different ammount of rows, you need to avoid IndexOutOfRange exception by checking each dgv rows count.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HorizontalScrollingOffset` (or `VerticalScrollingOffset`).

```
this.dataGridViewDataSample.HorizontalScrollingOffset
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set up an event-like scenario, where whenever scrollbar A's "value" changes, change scrollbar B to the appropriate value as well.

(Note that value is a property of a scroll bar, I do not mean the value of the data inside the container.)

Please see the following msdn article regarding that property of a scroll bar for better reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.value.aspx

And the class itself --
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `DataGridViews` in `Panels` and use this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panel1.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(panel1_Scroll);
}

void panel1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    panel2.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0,e.NewValue);
}
```

Unfortunately it does not seem that `DataGridView` has this property.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.xs4all.nl/~wrb/Articles_2010/Article_DataGridViewScroll_01.htm

This link shows exactly what I needed and worked fine for me.  The only problem I have now is that the datagrids does not have same rows in it. So even when one finishes (no more to scroll) the other must be able to continue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823188/how-can-i-sync-the-scrolling-of-two-multiline-textboxes). i wanted to sync two listviews when i scroll any of them. u can achieve this using custom controls. code works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

```
_dataGridViewInput.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(_dataGridViewInput_Scroll);
_dataGridViewOutput.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(_dataGridViewOutput_Scroll);

void _dataGridViewInput_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    this._dataGridViewOutput.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this._dataGridViewInput.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
}

void _dataGridViewOutput_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    this._dataGridViewInput.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this._dataGridViewOutput.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
}
```

Comment: Just Rowindex Property.  Obviously you need to code when row index differs to take care of Exceptions.

If you looking for Complex solutions - >  Read the code on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39244/Scroll-Synchronization( very intersting)