# Scrolling list view when another list view is scrolled

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scroll

in my win forms app, I am using two List views to compare two files.
when user selects two files using folder browser, files are loaded in List views. 
I compare the files and lines that are not matching are shown with different color.
this works absolutely fine.
now when I scroll one List view, I want the other List view should also be scrolled with same amount. 
I tried but you cannot set Horizontal scroll or vertical scroll property of a Listview.
how can I do this ? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823188/how-can-i-sync-the-scrolling-of-two-multiline-textboxes
also, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220343/c-sharp-windows-form-2-gridviews-with-synced-scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a custom List view so that you can detect it scrolling and pass the scroll message to the other text box so it will scroll in sync.

```
 class SyncListView: ListView
{
    public SyncListView()
    {
    }

    public Control Buddy { get; set; }

    private static bool scrolling;   // In case buddy tries to scroll us

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
    {
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    // Trap WM_VSCROLL message and pass to buddy
    if ((m.Msg == 0x115 || m.Msg == 0x20a) && !scrolling && Buddy != null && Buddy.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        scrolling = true;
        SendMessage(Buddy.Handle, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
        scrolling = false;
    }
}

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

}
```

Comment: How about when you drag the scroll slide and mouse left button pressed you move the slide up and down, them the buddy list view doesn't react to the scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar task. Two lists that must show theirs items next to each-other.

I found this thread with the Iorn Man's answer, that looked too difficult for me, because I did not have enough experience in C#.

I've found an easier solution for that.
I added a timer to a form. For its tick event, I added this:

```
Form active_form = Form.ActiveForm;
if (active_form == null) return;
Control control = Form.ActiveForm.ActiveControl;
if (control == newFilesList)
{
  Sync_lists(newFilesList);
}
else
{
  Sync_lists(oldFilesList);
}
```

It checks which list is active and calls Sync_list routine with this list as argument.

```
private void Sync_lists(ListView sender)
    {
        if ((newFilesList.Items.Count > 0) && (oldFilesList.Items.Count > 0))
        {
            int cur_top_index = sender.TopItem.Index;
            ListViewItem future_top_item;
            if (sender == oldFilesList)
            {
                future_top_item = newFilesList.Items[cur_top_index];
                newFilesList.TopItem = future_top_item;
            }
            else
            {
                future_top_item = oldFilesList.Items[cur_top_index];
                oldFilesList.TopItem = future_top_item;
            }
        }
    }
```

It just get TopItem property of the base list and sets item with the same index as a top for another list.

It is not so right as a custom ListView. But a little bit simpler. Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) or [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) using only managed code:

```
public class CustomListView : BetterListView
{
    public void SynchronizeScroll(BetterListView listView)
    {
        VScrollBar.Value = listView.VScrollProperties.Value;
    }
}
```

then handling its VScrollPropertiesChanged event with something like this:

```
    private void ListViewVScrollPropertiesChanged(object sender, BetterListViewScrollPropertiesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        CustomListView listViewThis = (sender as CustomListView);

        listViewThis.SynchronizeScroll(this.listViewAnother);
    }
```