# How to synchronise horizontal scrolling in DataGridViews

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have three DataGridViews: dgvSTART; dgvFilter; dgvEdit.

I have edited the scroll event for dgvSTART, inline with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220343/c-sharp-windows-form-2-gridviews-with-synced-scroll), which looks like:

```
dgvEdit.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = dgvSTART.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;
dgvFilter.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = dgvSTART.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;
```

This works, but only scrolls the other two DataGridViews when the left hand column of dgvSTART changes (ie the column dissapears/appears off the side of the panel).

Is it possible to make all the datagridviews scroll as one (ignoring the column boundaries)?

I think this is possible using the [HorizontalScrollingOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.horizontalscrollingoffset.aspx) property of the DataGridView, but my attempt was unsuccessful:

```
private void dgvSTART_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        //using matching the first column shown
        dgvEdit.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = dgvSTART.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;
        dgvFilter.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = dgvSTART.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;

        try
        {
            //trying to use horizontalscrollingoffset
            if (e.NewValue < e.OldValue)
            {
                dgvEdit.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dgvFilter.HorizontalScrollingOffset - 10;
                dgvFilter.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dgvFilter.HorizontalScrollingOffset - 10;
            }
            else
            {
                dgvEdit.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dgvEdit.HorizontalScrollingOffset + 10;
                dgvFilter.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dgvFilter.HorizontalScrollingOffset + 10;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }//do nothing with the exception        
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this code ?

`dataGridView_Scroll` need to be registered in the constructor of the form or something.

```
dgvSTART.Scroll  += new ScrollEventHandler(dataGridView_Scroll);
dgvFilter.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(dataGridView_Scroll);
dgvEdit.Scroll   += new ScrollEventHandler(dataGridView_Scroll);
```

`dataGridView_Scroll`  is as follows.

```
void dataGridView_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView src;
    DataGridView dst1 = null;
    DataGridView dst2 = null;

    src = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (src == dgvSTART)
    {
        dst1 = dgvFilter;
        dst2 = dgvEdit;
    }
    else if (src == dgvFilter)
    {
        dst1 = dgvSTART;
        dst2 = dgvEdit;
    }
    else if (src == dgvEdit)
    {
        dst1 = dgvSTART;
        dst2 = dgvFilter;
    }

    if (dst1 != null && dst2 != null)
    {
        dst1.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dst2.HorizontalScrollingOffset = src.HorizontalScrollingOffset;

        dst1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Math.Min(dst1.RowCount - 1, src.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex);
        dst2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Math.Min(dst2.RowCount - 1, src.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but it's jumpy when it draws the grid. Any ideas about how to stop this?

Comment: It is the same in the case of a single datagridview.
When a user drags the scroll bar, the grid scrolls smooth.
When a user click the arrow button of the scroll bar, the grid scrolls jumpy.

Comment: Smoothness can be achieved by providing equal to difference of e.NewValue < e.OldValue