# is there any way to use scrollbar to scroll 3 different textboxes together?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, scrollbar

I want to scroll 3 different `TextBoxes`.

I found some way in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823188/how-can-i-sync-the-scrolling-of-two-multiline-textboxes). but in VS2012 I cannot using `Windows.Forms` which very annoying. I did try to add references but I found no `Windows.Form` there this is the screenshot:

[image]
[image]

So I found an idea to use scrollbar, is it possible?

Comment: Is your application Winforms? WPF?

Comment: screenshot url seems broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.gbogea.com/2009/07/08/how-to-keep-two-scrollviewers-in-sync-in-wpf

there is the code. will copy paste here as mirror if the site goes down:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Name="scrollViewerLeft" ScrollChanged="scrollViewerLeft_ScrollChanged">
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        ...
        <ListBoxItem>100</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Name="scrollViewerMiddle">
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        ...
        <ListBoxItem>100</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
 </ScrollViewer>
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" Name="scrollViewerRight">
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        ...
        <ListBoxItem>100</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
 </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind:

```
private void scrollViewerLeft_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewerMiddle.ScrollToVerticalOffset((sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset);
    scrollViewerRight.ScrollToVerticalOffset((sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset);
}
private void scrollViewerMiddle_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewerLeft.ScrollToVerticalOffset((sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset);
    scrollViewerRight.ScrollToVerticalOffset((sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset);
}
private void scrollViewerRight_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewerLeft.ScrollToVerticalOffset((sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset);
    scrollViewerMiddle.ScrollToVerticalOffset((sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to use the `windows.forms` namespace you need to add the `System.windows.forms` library to your project: Rightclick `References` (Solution Explorer) -> `Add Reference` -> `.NET`-Tab -> select `System.Windows.Forms` and click ok.

Then you can import the System.Windows.Forms Namespace in every File you'll need it.

Comment: there is a message "all of framework assembly are already referenced"