# Vertical Scroll bars and displaying data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Im trying to control either two richtextbox's or two listboxs scrollbars with 1 vscrollbar. I want to display some data in a table like format, with 1 list separated from the other for asthetic purposes and would like the information to stay together line by line.

Does anybody know how to achieve this or perhaps a better way of doing this?

Comment: which answer do you want VBA or VB.NET?  there are not interchangable

Comment: Sorry. Well it's visual studio. So I assume .net

Comment: The technique in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3823319/17034) works for RichTextBox and ListBox as well.  You do need to tag your questions better, there are far too many implementations of these classes around (Winforms, WPF, Webforms, Silverlight, Store, Phone, Office).  The linked answer only works for Winforms.