# How to control two lists in winforms though one single slider just like in any compare file software

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to compare two text files like below, so I want to add one slide bar, as we side down it will slide both list boxes simultaneously on the same index and slide bar can go till the end to biggest Listbox.  Just like any file compares software e.g. Beyond compare.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823188/how-can-i-sync-the-scrolling-of-two-multiline-textboxes)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this by using the `Scroll` event. Both scrollbars need to handle the `Scroll` event like so:

```
private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    this.vScrollBar2.Scroll -= vScrollBar2_Scroll;
    this.vScrollBar2.Value = (sender as ScrollBar).Value;
    this.vScrollBar2.Scroll += vScrollBar2_Scroll;
}

private void vScrollBar2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    this.vScrollBar1.Scroll -= vScrollBar1_Scroll;
    this.vScrollBar1.Value = (sender as ScrollBar).Value;
    this.vScrollBar1.Scroll -= vScrollBar1_Scroll;
}
```

Please note when `vScrollBar1` is scrolling, we will tell `vScrollBar2` to scroll. Therefore, we do not want to trigger `vScrollBar2.Scroll` since it will come back and tell `vScrollBar1` to scroll at that instance (circular calls). Therefore we unsubscribe `vScrollBar2.Scroll` event temporarily. After `vScrollBar2` has scroll to the same position as `vScrollBar1`, then we tell `vScrollBar2` tp subscribe to its scroll event again. The same story with the other scrollbar.