# Horizontal Scroll Bar Event

Tags: c#, scroll, listbox, horizontal-scrolling

I have created an array of `ListBox` in which I have populated with some data from a text file. I want to change between each `Listbox` when the user scrolls either left or right so each one can be displayed. How would I go about doing this? I have populated my user interface with the first List-box `Listbox(0)`.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Exact same idea [as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3823319/17034), use WM_HSCROLL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but if you are trying to put the scrollbar to the left side of the listbox, you can set the `RightToLeft` property to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move from one ListBox to another the better control to use is a `Slider` then a ScrollBar